# How to add 1 to a variable after one tick?

Tags: netlogo

I try to add a number (1) to a part of the turtles after a tick. The function should always add one to the variable after one tick but currently, the function adds it only one time - after the first tick and then stops. The variable "updated_prob" is currently not steadily updated.

This is how the Goprocess looks like

```
to go     
  
  ask turtles[
  ifelse (color = grey)     
    [update_update_prob]     
    [e-bikenutzung]]         
  tick   

end

  to e-bikenutzung                  
  ask turtles with [color = green]   
  [if ticks = 48                    
  [set color grey                    
      set ebike? false             
      set probability_ebike_start 50]]  
end

to update_update_prob
  ask turtles with [color = grey]
  [set prob_sum probability_ebike_start + environment_add + subventionierung_bonus]
  
  ask turtles with [color = grey]
  [set updated_prob prob_sum + 1]   ------- is not steadily updated
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a typo in your code? The statement

```
set updated_prob prob_sum + 1
```

adds 1 to `prob_sum`, not to `updated_prob` and if `prob_sum` doesn't change from tick to tick, neither will `updated_prob`.  Do you want

```
set updated_prob updated_prob + 1
```

instead?

Your code also has a lot of redundancies.  If `update_update_prob` is executed only for grey turtles, then you don't need in `update_update_prob` to ask only gray turtles to do what you are doing in that procedure.  Only gray turtles will execute it anyway.  With lots of turtles, that can add a lot of overhead.

```
to update_update_prob
  [set prob_sum probability_ebike_start + environment_add + subventionierung_bonus]
  [set updated_prob updated_prob + 1]
end
```

should do it.